# How to use non-online images in CSS?

Tags: html, css, image

How do I use a non online picture (no `www.sth.com/image`) in my HTML *(or in CSS)* site?

Normally when I use a picture I do `<img src="link of image">` but how do I use a picture that I have **locally** on my computer?

Comment: Try something like this: `<img src="file:///C:/path/to/image.png">`, assuming you are using windows

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If, for example, your image is in the directory `images/image.png`, relative to the HTML file

You would use `<img src="images/image.png" />`. This will work both online and locally.

Answer (score 1):

If you are accessing the page locally then **use relative URLs**

If you are hosting the page on a server and visiting it yourself, then you could try to **use `file://` scheme URIs** but you might find yourself blocked by browser security restrictions (which don't allow webpages to fiddle with user's local disks). You'd be better off **hosting the image over HTTP**.

If you are hosting the page on a server and letting other people visit it, then you must **host the image over HTTP**. Your website visitors do not, and should not, be able to access your local hard disk.

Answer (score 1):

You can just enter the path of the file on your computer for the `src` attribute.

For example, if your image is in `C:/files/image.jpg`, just use `<img src="C:/files/image.jpg' />` and you can also use relative paths.

But, note that this only works on your local machine and will generate a 404 error on other machines that don't have the image in the exact same location.